# Searching for a nice way to define rules for decompiler, need advice

Tags: mips, decompiling, disassembly, opcode, control-flow

I am working on a very simple decompiler for MIPS architecture and as I progress I have to define lots of rules for code analysis, for example "if this opcode is *lui* and next opcode is *addiu* then return *var = value*" or "if this opcode is *bne* and it's referring to address before current - create *loop* definition in parsing tree". The problem - there are tons of such rules and I can't find a good way to define them. I've tried writing separated functions for every rule, defining nice OOP base logic classes and extending them to create rules, even tried regular expressions on disasmed code(to my surprise this works better than expected) but no matter what I've tried, my code soon became to big and to hard to read no matter how well I am trying to document and structure it.

This brings me to conclusion, that I am trying to solve this task by using wrong tools(not to mention being too stupid for such complex task :) ), but I have no real idea what should I try. Currently I have two untested ideas, one is using some kind of DSL(I have absolutely no experience in this, so I can be totally wrong), and another is writing some kind of binary regexp-like tools for opcode matching.

I hope someone can point me in correct direction, thx.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to write a decompiler just by looking at instruction patterns. Code flow and data analysis is necessary to correctly construct code blocks and expressions.

Comment: AFAIK opcode pattern observation is the way to get code flow, like in my second example(you find bne opcode which refers to address before itself = this is a loop), but you're right that it's only one of the steps, as I need to calculate condition for this loop, which means that I need to look at code before and check memory\registers modifications. So, this is two pass analysis - first build flow tree, than calculate everything inside.

Comment: The binary regex method actually sounds like a pretty good idea. The only other thing I can think of would be to write a MIPS frontend to LLVM, and use the C backend to get code (though I have no idea how readable the generated code would be, e.g it might use `goto`s for loops and recycle variables, etc.)

Comment: Thx for suggestion, I will definitely try LLVM, but I am afraid that it will produce code without knowing internals of MIPS and exact hardware which can sometime aid in getting additional info.
I am testing DSL approach right now, trying to copy the way I decompile code on the paper. :) And thx for fixing tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that some of your rules are too low-level, and that's why they're becoming unmanageable.

Recognising `lui` followed by `addiu` as a 32-bit constant load certainly seems very reasonable; but trying to derive control flow from branch instructions at the individual opcode level seems rather more suspect - I think you want to be working with basic blocks there.

Cifuentes' [Reverse Compilation Techniques](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.52.6990) is a reference which keeps cropping up in discussions of decompilation that I've seen; from a fairly brief skim, it seems like it would be well worth spending some time reading in detail for your project.

Some of the x86-specific stuff won't be relevant - in particular, the step which translates x86 to a low-level intermediate representation is probably not necessary for MIPS (MIPS is essentially just one basic operation per opcode already) - but otherwise much of the content looks like it should be very useful.

Comment: Oh my, this is excellent source of papers worse reading, I can't express how thankful I am (please, don't ask me how I was able to miss this :) )